# Android FragmentPagerAdapter : react to a fragment becoming visible

Tags: android

An Activity uses a FragmentPagerAdapter with two Tabs (and a fragment for each tab).
At first, only the Home fragment is visible, and the Run fragment is not.

```
tabsPageAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
...
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
...
viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPageAdapter);
```

The FragmentPagerAdapter looks a bit like this :

```
class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0: {
            return Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class.getName());
        }
        case 1:
            return Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, RunFragment.class.getName());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

When an Async Task in the Home Fragment succeeds, it notifies the Activity to show the Run Fragment.

```
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

This makes the RunFragment visible, but it calls none of the lifecycle methods :

- onCreate (which makes sense, since it has already been created before)
- onResumed

Unfortunately, I need some code in the RunFragment to run at this moment (it can not run before, since it depends on side effects of code that was run in the HomeFragment.)

I tried :

- using the lifecycle methods (none seem to be called)
- keeping a reference to the RunFragment in the MainActivity ; this does not work, as the reference to the RunFragment ends up being "null" from time to time (or it is not null, but its reference to getActivity() is null)

How would I attack this ?

Comment: "This makes the RunFragment visible, but it calls none of the lifecycle methods" -- I presume that you mean `onResume()`. Those would have been called as part of the fragment being created, which occurred up front. `ViewPager` creates three pages initially (or less if there are fewer than three possible pages). "I need some code in the RunFragment to run at this moment" -- call a method on `RunFragment` at the point when you call `setCurrentItem(1)`.

Comment: "this does not work, as the reference to the RunFragment ends up being "null" from time to time (or it is not null, but its reference to getActivity() is null)" -- post the complete stack trace, plus the relevant `RunFragment` code.